# Show count 0 when condition is not met in MySQL group by

Tags: mysql, sql

Sample Records:

```
examid      setcode     answer
-------     --------   --------
10            A           A
10            A           B
10            A           X
10            B           A
10            B           B
10            B           C
```

I am trying to find count group by setcode where answer is X.
I have tried the following query:

```
SELECT setCode,COUNT(answer) FROM mcq_answer WHERE examid=10 AND answer='X' GROUP BY setCode
```

This one is returning the following result:

```
setcode     count
-------     -------- 
A            1
```

But I am looking for the following:

```
setcode     count
-------    -------- 
  A           1 
  B           0
```

Setcode is dynamic here. I have mentioned A and B only. There may be more setocdes as C,D,E,F etc. How can I do it. I am using `MySQL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SUM + IF` to have this result:

```
SELECT `setCode`, SUM(if (`answer`='X', 1,0)) as answer 
FROM `mcq_answer`
WHERE examid=10
GROUP BY `setcode`
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use below query

```
SELECT  C.setCode ,
    SUM(CASE WHEN B.setcode IS NULL THEN 0
             ELSE 1
        END) AS answer
FROM    ( SELECT    A.setCode ,
                COUNT(1) AS cnt
      FROM      mcq_answer A
      GROUP BY  A.setCode
    ) C
    LEFT JOIN mcq_answer b ON C.setcode = B.setcode
                              AND B.answer = 'X'
 GROUP BY  C.setCode
```

Comment: Setcode is dynamic here. I have mentioned A and B only. There may be more setocdes as C,D,E,F etc. I am sorry I didn't mention it. I have edited my question @Hasmukh Viradiya

Comment: this query will also work for dynamic setcode. have you tried this query?
i have not make query for fix setcode like A and B

Comment: There is total 80 rows per setcode where setocode A contains 2 'X' answers, secode B contains 4 'X' answers and setcode C has no 'X' answers. The query is returning the following result:
for setcode A the count is 160, for setcode B the count is 320 and for setcode C the count is 0. I think total row is being multiplied with the count for each setocode
@Hasmukh Viradiya

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT A.setcode, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN B.answer ='X' THEN B.answer ELSE NULL END) as count_x
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT setcode FROM YOUR_TABLE) A
LEFT JOIN
YOUR_TABLE B
ON A.setcode = B.setcode
GROUP BY A.setcode;
```

It also works for dynamic set of values for `setcode`.